# How to change policy file for applet printing

Tags: java

Printing is not supported in Java applets by default. How can I change the java.policy file for applet printing? I want to print from the applet.

Also, this method returns NULL for me:

```
PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService()
```

Please provide references and sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Depends where you need to use that applet. If you need only one single workstation then you are better of running it as application instead of an applet.

If it is feasible you can also deploy a matching policy on every client machine or use a signed applet.

Here a few relevant links

[Java Plugin Guide](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/contents.html) -> especially Part III

[signed Applets : Java Glossary](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/signedapplets.html)

[Java Tutorial Signed Applets](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html) -> somewhat dated tutorial

[Default Policy Implementation and Policy File Syntax](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html) -> all you could possibly want to know about policy files and how to make them

Comment: i need to use applet instead of application, because its my requirement.
do u know the entry for enable permission for printing for applet.

Answer (score 0):

When you attempt to print from applet, the user should be presented with a dialog asking to print. IIRC, if denied a `SecurityException` will be thrown as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and I solved it by adding the following line in Java.policy file:

```
permission java.security.AllPermission;
```

but stil not able to find out the exact permission which is required. Giving All permissions is not safe for applets.